# Dixmier averaging Theorem

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

We know the standard result of Dixmier averaging Theorem for von Neumann algebras. Is Dixmier averaging Theorem still holds for $C^{*}$-algebras??

Comment: What is the statement of this theorem?

Comment: The statement is following: let $A$ in vN algebra $M$, $\mathcal{u}(M)$ is unitary group of $M$ , The norm closed convex hull of $\{uAu^{*}:u \in \mathcal{u}(M)\}$ intersects center of $M$.

Comment: In the second paragraph of the introduction to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08263.pdf), the authors state that in Dixmier's original paper he gives an example of a $C^*$-algebra for which the result fails.